# clearRect issue in animation

Tags: html, canvas, frame

Im having issue with clearRect, i have an image u can move up and down and which follow the angle where the mousse is but in some frames of the animation the clearRect let a small edge of the previous image state ( 'this' reference to the image and 'ctx' is the 2d context, 'this.clear()' is called each frame before redrawing the image at the new coordinates )

```
this.clear = function(){
    game.ctx.save();
    game.ctx.translate(this.x+this.width/2, this.y+this.height/2);//i translate to the old image center
    game.ctx.rotate(this.angle);//i rotate the context to the good angle
    game.ctx.clearRect(this.width/-2, this.height/-2, this.width, this.height);//i clear the old image
    game.ctx.restore();
};
```

if i replace the clearRect line by

```
game.ctx.clearRect(this.width/-2-1, this.height/-2-1, this.width+2, this.height+2);
```

it works but its not the logical way

Comment: This seems like it might be an issue with sub-pixel rendering. Are your this.x and this.y values guaranteed to be ints or are they floats sometimes?

Comment: +1 for @ZachBabb, with this additional question : are width/height even or odd ?

Comment: Yes widht height x and y are all integer, it happen only when the image have an angle different from 0 when i go up and dow at 0rad there is no leftover

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only clearing at position half the width/height, not *position* minus half the width/height.

Regarding anti-aliasing: when you do a rotation there will be anti-aliased pixels regardless of the original position being integer values. This is because after the pixels relative positions are run through the transformation matrix their offsets will in most cases be float values.

Try to change this line:

```
game.ctx.clearRect(this.width/-2, this.height/-2, this.width, this.height);
```

to this instead including compensation for anti-aliased pixels (I'll split the lines for clearity):

```
game.ctx.clearRect(this.x - this.width/2 - 1,   /// remember x and y
                   this.y - this.height/2 - 1,
                   this.width + 2, 
                   this.height + 2);
```

Comment: ok so i must add some extra width and height for the aliased pixel there is no other solutions?

Comment: @user3191059 you can try to turn off interpolation for images using the property `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false` but it doesn't seem to work with rotation (last time I checked), only scale/resize.